# mac os x install dvd

Tags: macos, mac, xcode

I got my first Macbook Pro with a DVD for Mac OS X, do i need to install it if I want to use [xcode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/)? what operating system is currently running on my mac? What is the difference between them ?

Comment: If you can't work out what operating system you're running, Xcode probably isn't for you.

Comment: wow that is a very helpful comment .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be Mac OS X installed on your MacBook and you don't have to install it on your own.

XCode is on the Installation DVD.

Answer (score 2):

[How to install XCode on Mac OS X](http://permadi.com/blog/?p=17). You computer has Mac OS X is installed. [Here are the differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X#Versions) in the versions.  Xcode is only an IDE (intergrated development environment.) Are you sure you need to use xcode?

Answer (score 0):

**What operating system is currently running on my mac?**

Is this a joke or you really don't know? Haven't the guy at the shop told you anything about the computer you've bought? If he didn't, just check the [MacBook Pro specification](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs.html) on the Apple website which says:

> Software
>
> - Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard (includes iTunes, Time Machine, Quick
>     Look, Spaces, Spotlight, Dashboard,
>     Mail, iChat, Safari, Address Book,
>     QuickTime, iCal, DVD Player, Photo
>     Booth, Front Row, Xcode Developer
>     Tools)

So, you have Mac OS X installed on your computer.

Here you can find basic [overview about developer tools](http://www.apple.com/macosx/developers/#xcode) you've got included. Alternatively, you can also [download XCode 3](http://developer.apple.com/technology/tools.html)

Finally, read the [Xcode Installation Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeCoexistence/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Introduction/Introduction.html)